# Webpack import returns undefined, depending on the order of imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using webpack + babel. I have three modules looking like this:

```js
// A.js

// some other imports here
console.log('A');
export default 'some-const';

// B.js

import someConst from './A';
console.log('B', someConst);
export default 'something-else';

// main.js

import someConst from './A';
import somethingElse from './B';
console.log('main', someConst);
```

When `main.js` is executed, I see the following:

```
B undefined
A
main some-const
```

If I swap the imports in `main.js`, `B` becoming the first, I get:

```
A
B some-const
main some-const
```

How come `B.js` gets `undefined` instead of a module in the first version? What's wrong?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

After almost a full workday of narrowing down the issue (AKA hair-pulling), I've finally came to realize that I have a circular dependency.

Where it says `// some other imports here`, `A` imports another module `C`, which, in turn, imports `B`. `A` gets imported first in `main.js`, so `B` ends up being the last link in the "circle", and Webpack (or any CommonJS-like environment, for that matter, like Node) just short-circuits it by returning `A`'s `module.exports`, which is still `undefined`. Eventually, it becomes equal to `some-const`, but the synchronous code in `B` ends up dealing with `undefined` instead.

Eliminating the circular dependency, by moving out the code that `C` depends on out of `B`, has resolved the issue. Wish Webpack would somehow warn me about this.

**Edit:** On the last note, as pointed out by @cookie, [there's a plugin for circular dependency detection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin), if you'd like to avoid hitting this problem [again].

Comment: there is a plugin for webpack that'll detect circular dependencies: https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin

Comment: You are a freaking hero.  Webpack is such a dumpster fire---this just blew up my vue.js site.  It turns out that if component X imports vuex state Y + js module Z, and Y and Z both import the same JSON FILE, somehow that constitutes a circular dependency.  Would have never fixed it but for this SO.

Comment: So... if webpack emits broken code because it doesn't support circular dependencies (I'm not arguing it should support bad design), then how come we need a plugin that tells us that we have a problem?

Comment: @joonas.fi: I agree. IMO with the JS ecosystem it usually comes down to https://www.jwz.org/doc/worse-is-better.html

Answer (score 1):

This [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin)(pointed above) solved the issue for me as well.

I recommend setting this flag to avoid adding additional circular dependencies in the future.

```
// add errors to webpack instead of warnings
failOnError: true
```

There is also a eslint [plugin](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-cycle.md) to address it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was solved by changing output libraryTarget to commonjs2 in the webpack config:

```
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
```