# Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vuefire

I'm building a simple web app with Vue + Firebase + Vuefire and I get **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined"** when I try to use my Firebase db variable inside a component.

### In main.js

```
Vue.use(VueFire)

const firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp({ //setting })

// Export the database for components to use.
export const db = firebaseApp.database()
```

### And in my component

```
// in Recipes.vue
import {db} from '../main.js'

export default {
  recipe: {
    source: db.ref('recipes')
    // Console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined"
  }
}
```

I followed the steps in this tutorial https://alligator.io/vuejs/vuefire-firebase/

This code `db.ref('recipes')` works if used inside main.js, but it never works once I import it inside my component.

Comment: The immediate difference I see between your code and the tutorial is that you're including the `.js` extension when importing. Perhaps you should try omitting that and instead use `import {db} from '../main'`. Granted, I've never used the importing or exporting, so I can't say whether or not this will remedy your problem.

Comment: Good observation. I never noticed it could work without the .js extension. I gave it a try, the path still works, but I have the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my Firebase code (including db variable) was inside `main.js` but it needed to be in it's own component. I created a `firebase.js` file :

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp({
  # configuration
})

// Export the database for components to use.
export const db = firebaseApp.database()
```

Then in my component I simply imported my database variable :

```
import {db} from '../firebase'
```

Why didn't it work inside `main.js`? I'm not sure, maybe someone more knowledgeable can answer that.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240716/webpack-import-returns-undefined-depending-on-the-order-of-imports

Answer (score 0):

`.ref` is a firebase function, you need to import it. try

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'
```

or

```
import * from 'firebase'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I eventually found the answer. I posted the solution in a separate answer.