# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Firebase in my Nodejs project but I keep getting an error and I cannot figure it out.

my firebase.ts

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import "firebase/database"
const config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const databaseRef = firebase.database();
export default firebase;
```

index.ts

```
export * from './firebase';
```

Where it is used

```
import { databaseRef } from '../../common/services/firebase'

await databaseRef.ref('dummy')
```

I got this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Comment: The init code and database creation looks correct but your export is fine as well. That leads me to believe the databaseRef is undefined after the `firebase.database()` call. Have you tried logging that variable in the `firebase.ts` file?

Comment: no @SpecialCharacter I am just confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253938/cannot-read-property-ref-of-undefined)

Comment: databaseRef is undefined. but why?

Comment: @BiswajitPanday the solution there is similar to what I have here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting `firebase.database()` first, try exporting `firebase.initializeApp(config)`

If the file is to be loaded a second time, check for the existing firebase app instance first.

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging but the logic should be similar:

```
// Dependencies
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

// Service account creds
const serviceAccount = require('../../creds/creds.json');

// Initalize the firebase app
const config = {
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
};

// Check for existing firebase app instance
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    // Create a new one if there is none
    const fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    module.exports = { fb, };
} else {
    // otherwise export the existing one
    const fb = firebase.app();
    module.exports = { fb, };
}
```